# How to calculate last 3 months average growth rate as of snapshot date in Jupyter python?

Tags: python, spyder, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a dataset as below where we want to follow snapshot based approach( that is as of 3 snapshot dates in the dataset, what is the performance). Apologies I am new in jupyter(Python)

| Cust ID | Reporting Date | Snapshot date | Number of debits | Number of credits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | JUN'21 | SEP'21 | 5 | 5 |
| C1 | JULY'21 | SEP'21 | 6 | 8 |
| C1 | AUG'21 | SEP'21 | 7 | 1 |
| C1 | SEP'21 | SEP'21 | 5 | 10 |

Here there is 12 month(June'21-May'22) reporting data & 3 snapshots month merged into the data( Sep, oct & nov'21). For multiple variables I need to find 3 month growth rates as of every snapshot(standing in snapshot date sep'21 -- what is the 3 month growth rate of cust id), similarly for october & november snapshot.

Comment: This is not an accounting/ commerce platform!

Comment: I am seeking help to perform this in python